# Does piping between two external processes save memory?

Tags: perl, memory

I was doing this to run an external command, prepend some data and send it all to another external command:

```
my $prepend = 'foo foo foo';
my $contents = `command`;
open(my $handle, "|-", "command_2"))
print $handle $prepend . $contents;
close $handle;
```

Which is fine for when `$contents` (returned from an external process) is small (it's often less than 1k), but when it's big (up to 10, 20, 30MB), I suspect this is unnecessarily memory intensive.

So I changed it to:

```
my $prepend = 'foo foo foo';
open(my $handle_in, "-|", "command"))
open(my $handle_out, "|-", "command_2"))
print $handle_out $prepend;
while (<$handle_in>) {
    print $handle_out $_;
}
close $handle_in;
close $handle_out;
```

Does this actually save memory? When `command` returns many MB of data, does it suffer any performance problems? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use `File::Copy` to copy the input to the output file handle. http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html

Comment: @shawnhcorey thanks. Looks like it has buffer size control as well. Do you know if there is any real difference between what I did and using it? Is it perhaps the same or is it optimized better?

Comment: `File::Copy` is a standard module and is installed with Perl. If standard modules can be optimized, they usually are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you read the entirety of the output of `command` into memory before sending any of it out. In the second case, you read only a line at a time.

If the output of command is large and consists of many lines, then yeah, you'll save memory.

There's more work being done in the second case, so it'll be slower, but probably unnoticeably so.